# Is it possible not to give your bounty away?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19260/why-do-we-get-cold-feet) had a bounty, and the sign there says the bounty ended 35 minutes ago, but no on has the bounty yet, so I'm just wondering :

1. Did the Altruist manage to take back his bounty?
2. How did he do it?

Comment: I believe if the bounty is not awarded, it disappears.  You don't get it back.  Otherwise, why award it?  Just offer the bounty and abscond with your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A recent change to the bounty system causes the auto-award system to wait 24 hours after the end of the bounty before awarding it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037)

Answer (score 0):

I can explain what happened from my end of things.

I offered the bounty seven days ago. Some good new answers came in, particularly [yours](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19260/why-do-we-get-cold-feet/31011#31011) and [@TimLymington's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19260/why-do-we-get-cold-feet/31409#31409). After looking into the question some more myself, however, I realized I was unconvinced that these earlier references could be tied directly to our modern sense of *cold feet*. There seemed to be too long a gap with no mention of the phrase and also further evidence that the phrase developed its current meaning in the early 1800s.

So, I decided to let the bounty expire, thinking you would get half of it (25 points) for your interesting and highly-upvoted answer. I was unaware of the new delay in the bounty system and was confused by the points not having been awarded 12 hours after the bounty expired. Out of curiosity, I thought I'd see what would happen if I clicked the bounty for my own revised answer (and because I didn't really feel any of the new answers deserved the full bounty). At first it didn't seem to do anything, but it did make the *+50* buttons disappear from the other answers. Now, though, I see that it seems to have awarded me back [10 points](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5822/callithumpian?tab=reputation) and made it look like I rescinded the bounty. I really didn't think this was possible, but I can't see a way to undo it.

Now, I'm curious if that will change after 24 hours pass. According to @waiwai's answer, half the bounty should go back to you at this point. If it does not, I think this may be a flaw in the bounty system that should be looked into.

Comment: The +10 was from an upvote (click the line to get a breakdown)—you awarded the bounty to yourself, which is a +0 award to prevent abuse of the bounty system, so the auto-award won't kick in.

Comment: @waiwai: So I gave up the bounty points, but prevented them from going to anyone else? Seems like that shouldn't be allowed.